# Not able to bind column data when there is space in json

Tags: sapui5

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <title>OData Date Table Multiple Sorters</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
        </script>
        <script>
          var airsideTableDataOriginal=
                //{"genericTableModel":
                [
                {"columnId":"col1","WS":"WS 1","Status":0},
                {"columnId":"col 2","WS":"WS 2","Status":1},
                {"columnId":"col3","WS":"WS 3","Status":2},
                {"columnId":"col4","WS":"WS 4","Status":3},
                {"columnId":"col5","WS":"WS 5","Status":4},

                 ];
        var aColumnData = [{
            columnId: "col1"
        }, {
            columnId: "col 2"
        }, {
            columnId: "col3"
        }, {
            columnId: "col4"
        }, {
            columnId: "col5"
        }];


        var aData = [{

            "col 2": "WS 2",
            col3: "WS 3",
            col4: "WS 4",
            col5: "WS 5"
        }];
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        oModel.setData({
            columns: aColumnData,
            rows: aData
        });

        var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
            title: "Table column and data binding",
            showNoData : true,  
            columnHeaderHeight : 10,
            visibleRowCount: 7
        });
        oTable.setModel(oModel);

        oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
             var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
          var tempJson=airsideTableDataOriginal;


             return new sap.ui.table.Column({
                id : sColumnId,
                label: sColumnId,
                template: new sap.ui.commons.Button({
              text : { 
                 path: sColumnId, 
                  formatter: function(value){
                    if(value!=null){
              var specificJson= $.grep(tempJson, function( n, i ) {
              return n.columnId === sColumnId.toString() && n.WS === value.toString();
              });   
                    if(specificJson[0].Status == 1){
                     this.setIcon("sap-icon://accept");
                     this.setStyle(sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Accept);            
                }
                }
                    if(value === "" || value == undefined){
                    this.setVisible(false);
                }
                       return  value ; 
                } 
                },
                }),


                sortProperty: sColumnId, 
                filterProperty: sColumnId
            });
        });
        oTable.bindRows("/rows");
        oTable.placeAt("content");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="body" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As per the above code there is `space` between `col 2` which gives error `"col 2" is not a valid ID.`. Here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/gusabosiqu/edit?html,output). But when I replace `col 2` with `col2` it works fine. But in real time I get spaces in data so how to fix it so that it would work with spaces also.

Comment: What stops you from removing the spaces or replacing them with an underscore for example?

Comment: @Qualiture.. client requirement. I did it the same way as you said but client want spaces. So is there any way.

Comment: This is the function that checks if an ID is valid. The regex does not allow spaces: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/9103a24a1800aacd02a5337f763270953c9aefe3/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/library.js#L871 You can suggest adding \s to the regex to allow spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess, that the error comes from the invalid ID of the Column object: `id : sColumnId,` (the first line after `return new sap.ui.table.Column({`)  and not from the binding.

Like Mark said in his comment Element IDs cannot contain spaces. But the ID is not visible to the User and you can just replace the spaces of the Column.id while assigning or you can skip the id assignment at all to get automaticaly generated ids.

Comment: Commenting out the id just works fine. However I tried this `id : { 
       path: sColumnId, 
        formatter: function(value){ return value.replace(/ /g,'');}},` but it doesn't work.

Comment: id is not bindable. you can do something like this in your code: `id: sColumnId.replace(/ /g, ''), `

Answer (score 0):

A client who demands spaces in their ID's I would 1) definitely steer clear from, and if that's not possible, 2) educate them that their "requirement" is utter [...]

Nevertheless, I would simply replace the spaces with underscores (it's really simple Javascript):

```
airsideTableDataOriginal.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.columnId = obj.columnId.replace(/ /g,"_");
});

aColumnData.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.columnId = obj.columnId.replace(/ /g,"_");
});

aData.forEach(function(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (~property.indexOf(" ")) {
                var newProperty = property.replace(/ /g,"_");
                obj[newProperty] = obj[property];
                delete obj[property];
            }
        }
    }
});
```